# How do I go from a pregenerated character with text and a statistics block to a normal character sheet?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

[image][image]

How can I take the Pre Generated character and write it out on to the blank sheet? I started, but now I’m completely lost.

Comment: Where did the pregenerated character come from?

Comment: @Miniman  http://www.dmsguild.com/product/171028/Pregen-Characters-High-Elf-Fighter-5e

Comment: This is one that I think will be easiest to deal with in [chat], so I'm throwing an upvote your way. When you've got 20 rep you'll be able to participate fully, should you like.

Comment: Are there specific issues that you are having? Obviously the name goes in the "Name" field and the "Armor Class" goes in the "Armor Class" field. Is there a particular stat on the sheet that is not making sense for how to transfer it to the sheet?